# SQL query returning more records in full join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a full join code for the following requirement:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POLJC.png)

The below output in the sample is the expected output. However when I am writing a full join query, I am getting a lot more number of records, than expected. The query is doing a cartesian product among both the tables. How can I get the desired output?

I have used the following query:

```
    select A.*,B.* from tableA full outer join tableB on A.Key=B.Key2
```

I also tried doing a union as follows:

```
    select Key,Date,Mov,null as Key2,null as Date2,null as Mov2 from tableA
    union all 
    select null as Key,null as Date,null as Mov,Key2,Date2,Mov2 from tableB
```

Even with the union, I did not get the desired result, as the records are not aligned properly.
I want to keep the records aligned as per the Key in table1 and key2 in table2. Thats the reason I used a full join, but getting a large number of records.

Can someone please help me with the query?

Edit: When I use union all, I get the result as follows:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipTSx.png)

The records adjacent to the table 1 are coming blank, and the contents of table 2 start only when the one from table 1 end.
This is not as what I want in the expected output above.

Comment: solution 2 the union all should work fine. I don't understand what you mean by not aligning. Post a create table statement, some insert statements,  and your desired results NOT pictures of desired results

Comment: It looks like you want to generate two columns of output, one containing the contents of your first table and the other with the contents of your second table. Please [edit] your question to clarify. And, please know that SQL isn't designed to do that: usually such things are done by client code.

Comment: @BryanDellinger I have added an edit to your comment. By alignment, I mean the records of table 2 should be adjacent to the table 1. Since I am trying to map it to the Key  from table1 and Key2 from table2

Comment: MySql does not even support FULL outer join. Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it has to be a composite key on 2 columns.  That's the only way both table's would have a unique key.

In table1 you could use the first column and date as primary key or first column and mov as a primary key, but in the second table it would have to be the key and mov.